# jsp doesn't redirect my post to a backend server and to another address

Tags: jsp, backend

```
http.open("POST", url, true);
                //http.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/json");
                http.onreadystatechange = function() {
                    if (http.readyState == 4 && http.status == 200) {
                        document.open();
                        document.write(http.responseText);
                    }
                };
                http.send();
```

this is how I do the post, and the server should transfer it to another address. but from some reason the response always get canceled.

any idea?

Comment: I actually got a cross a term called cross domain - is it helping?